# Offline messages not being send to Adafruit IoT portal by Mosquitto broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have a Raspberry Pi in which I have installed Mosquitto broker and MQTT. Pi is connected to sensor and  I need to send this data to `Adafruit IoT protal`. I am able to send all the data when the Pi is connected but when the Pi goes offline, I am only able to transmit data for 20-30 sec. If the Pi is offline for more than 2-3 mins then that data is not transmitted to portal.

I have created a bridge.conf file and add all the configurations to be used my Mosquitto. Here is the content:

```
connection iothub
address io.adafruit.com:1883
remote_username <username>
remote_password <password>
remote_clientid sensor1
bridge_cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
try_private false
cleansession false
start_type automatic
bridge_insecure false
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_tls_version tlsv1
notifications false
max_queued_messages 0
autosave_interval 5

topic # out 2 /sensors/sensor1
topic # in 2 /sensors/sensor1
```

I have set the `cleansession` false and using QOS 2. I have also set `max_queued_messages` to 0 which means maximum. The problem I am facing is if the Pi is offline for just 1-2 mins, I am able to get all the offline data but if it is offline for more than 3-4 mins, I don't receive any data.

Comment: `max_queued_messages`: 0 means "no maximum" and not "maximum" and it is not recommended as per: https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html.

Try to set some specific but large queue size and check the result.